# Looking for a *general* algorithm for generating standard PRBS sequences

Tags: c#, c++, c, algorithm, random

In electronics there are standard pseudo-binary sequences. In the literature they talk about the generating polynomials for these sequences:

```
PRBS-7  : x^7 + x^6 + 1
PRBS-10 : x^11 + x^10 + 1
PRBS-15 : x^15 + x^14 + 1
PRBS-23 : x^23 + x^18 + 1
PRBS-31 : x^31 + x^28 + 1
```

I was able to find on [Wikipedia - Pseudo-random binary sequence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pseudorandom_binary_sequence) a snippet of C code for generating PRBS-7 but there was no indication of how to convert this to create the other sequences.

Here is what I have, but other than for PRBS-7 it generates nothing but zeroes. This code is C# but I would be ok with C or C++ samples.

```
private static void Generate(int v1, int v2, StringBuilder roots, StringBuilder bits)
{
    // This works fine for PRBS7 with v1=7, v2=6 but fails for 15,10; 23,18; 31,28
    const byte start = 2;
    byte a = start;
    for (int i = 1; i < 2000; i++)  // I added the 2000 limit, otherwise was infinite loop
    {
        roots.AppendFormat("{0:X2} ", a);
        int newbit = (((a >> v1 - 1) ^ (a >> v2 - 1)) & 1); // my naive attempt to generalize the algorithm
        a = (byte)((byte)((a << 1) | newbit) & 0x7f);
        bits.Append(newbit);
        if (i % 32 == 0)
        {
            roots.AppendLine();
            bits.AppendLine();
        }
        if (a == start)
        {
            roots.AppendFormat("\r\nRepetition Period = {0}", i);
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This is neither C nor C++ code, so please do not tag either. If you are requesting the above code be translated for you, that is off topic for Stack Overflow,

Comment: Side note: "no indication how to convert" is somewhat false - https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_feedback_shift_register linked from the Wikipedia article shows plenty of background information/samples (is it the reason why you did not add link to Wikipedia yourself)?

Comment: So far question look too broad/unclear - code conversion is off-topic, Wikipedia provided plenty of info/samples already. Teaching what happens when one shifts byte by more than 8 and cast to byte was answered many times.

Comment: Not sure what you mean by off-topic. I found a code snippet but could not figure out how to make it work for anything but the PRBS-7 case. I am OK with an answer in C, C++, or C# so that is why I have tagged all 3. I am not looking for a translation, just help in getting code to work in the general case. I felt that the title of my post expressed this. Sorry if I wasn't clear.

Comment: Alexei - it probably is true that there are tons of samples on Wikipedia for shift registers which would be great except that isn't what I am interested in. What I am looking for is a general algorithm for generating the specific pseudo-random binary sequences known in the industry as PRBS7, PRBS15, PRBS23, and PRBS31. The only sample code I have been able to find only addresses PRBS7 and had no comments on how to use it for the other cases.

Comment: Check out this C++ templated implementation https://github.com/root-project/root/issues/8199#issuecomment-843369054

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure if this is what you want:

```
private static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var sequence = GeneratePrbSsequences(15);
            Console.WriteLine(string.Join("\n",sequence));
            Console.WriteLine("Repetition Period = {0}", sequence.Count);
            Console.ReadLine();
        }

    static List<string> GeneratePrbSsequences(int number)
    {
        var a = 0x02;
        var period = (int)(Math.Pow(2, number) - 1);
        var sequenceList = new List<string>();
        do
        {
            var v1 = number - 1;
            var v2 = number - 2;
            var newbit = (((a >> v1) ^ (a >> v2)) & 1);
            a = ((a << 1) | newbit) & period;
            sequenceList.Add(string.Format("{0:X2}", a));
            Console.WriteLine();
        } while (a != 0x02);
        return sequenceList;
    }
}
```

Comment: Ammar - with a few minor modifications to use both of the factors in the generating polynomials this looks really good. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Ammar gave an almost correct answer so I will be voting up his answer. But here is how I modified his answer to use both factors in the generating polynomial. I'm still not positive that this is totally correct but it does seem to provide usable results.

```
static void GeneratePrbSsequences(int v1, int v2)
{
    int a = 0x02;
    int period = (int)(Math.Pow(2, v1) - 1);
    v1--;
    v2--;
    for (int i=1;;i++)
    {
        var newbit = (((a >> v1) ^ (a >> v2)) & 1);
        System.Diagnostics.Debug.Write(newbit);
        if (i%8 == 0) 
        {
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.Write(" ");
            if (i%128 == 0) System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("");
        }
        a = ((a << 1) | newbit) & period;
        if (a == 0x02)
        {
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("");
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("Computed period = {0}, Actual period = {1}", period, i);
            break;
        }
    }
}
```